# Configuring Tomcat 6 Server on Plesk for Windows

Tags: tomcat6, windows-server-2008-r2, plesk

I've windows 2008 R2 Server with Plesk 11.0.9 installed. Plesk has inbuilt version of Tomcat 5.5 and which is working fine. Now we want to update Tomcat Server and we have installed Tomcat 6 in the same directory where previous version is installed. Then we start Tomcat 6 Service and stopped Tomcat 5.5 service. We also restarted the server but still in plesk panel in server component it shows Tomcat 5 version and Tomcat 5 service is running :( , no luck with tomcat 6.

I google it and every where i only see tomcat 6 installation for Plesk with  Linux server nothing for Plesk for Windows. Not even on Plesk forum.

We require to install konacart and for this we require tomacat 6, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to backup "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Tomcat" folder to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Tomcat5.5"(for example).

1. Stop Tomcat service.
2. Than unzip apache-tomcat-6.0.36-windows-x86.zip to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Tomcat" with overwriting content.
3. Than replace server.xml file from old Tomcat 5.5 folder("C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Tomcat5.5\conf\server.xml") to folder with Tomcat 6.0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Tomcat\conf\server.xml"
4. Than update key "ImagePath" in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tomcat5\ to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe" 
   //RS//Tomcat5 (Tomcat5 here it's just [service name](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) )
5. Start Tomcat service.

I have tested this configuration with *.war applications and it's working for me.
Also there was error message like "TomcatManager::installVHost "Can't find Engine PSA" - it's because I don't use server.xml from Tomcat 5.5